# Proftpd issue with filenames on FTPS

Tags: debian, ftp, proftpd

I'm setting up a proftpd service on a Debian 11 server.
I want to be able to connect the to FTP with local users (for administrators) and AD user.
I joined the Debian server to my AD using realmd and it's working fine for ssh connections.
*Note: domain user's home is on a NFS share.*

When I try to connect to the FTP with my Filezilla client and my local user it's working fine and filenames are correct.
But my issue is when I connect with my AD user in FTPS, the filenames are like : **users;UNIX.mode=0666;UNIX.owner=978115167;UNIX.ownername=myuser; file.txt**

I'm not even able to interact with this files (transfer, rename, delete) because I get a 550 error :

```
Status: Deleting "/users;UNIX.mode=0666;UNIX.owner=978115167;UNIX.ownername=myuser; file.txt"
13:01:44    Command:    DELE users;UNIX.mode=0666;UNIX.owner=978115167;UNIX.ownername=myuser; file.txt
13:01:44    Response:   550 users;UNIX.mode=0666;UNIX.owner=978115167;UNIX.ownername=myuser; file.txt: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

Same problem with WinSCP. However no problem using Proftpd's SFTP mod (because it's ssh I guess).

Here's my config file :

```
Include /etc/proftpd/modules.conf
ServerName  "ftp.domain.com"
UseIPv6 off
User    proftpd
Group   nogroup

Port    21

TransferLog /var/log/proftpd/xferlog
SystemLog   /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log

#
ServerType  standalone
DeferWelcome    off

MultilineRFC2228    on
DefaultServer   on
ShowSymlinks    on

TimeoutNoTransfer   600
TimeoutStalled  600
TimeoutIdle 1200

DisplayLogin    welcome.msg
DisplayChdir    .message true
ListOptions     "-l"

DenyFilter  \*.*/
#

<Global>
    DefaultRoot ~
    Umask   000 000
    CreateHome  on 777
    PassivePorts    20000 20200
    AllowOverwrite  on

    ######
    #TLS#
    ######
    TLSEngine   off
    TLSRSACertificateFile   /etc/ssl/certs/domain.com.crt
    TLSRSACertificateKeyFile    /etc/ssl/private/domain.com.key
    TLSCACertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ca.crt
    TLSOptions NoSessionReuseRequired
    TLSLog  /var/log/proftpd/tls.log
    TLSProtocol TLSv1.2
    TLSVerifyClient off
    TLSRequired on
</Global>

######
#FTPS#
######
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0>
    Port    990
    TLSEngine   on
    TLSOptions  UseImplicitSSL
    ListOptions     "-l"
</VirtualHost>

######
#SFTP#
######
<IfModule mod_sftp.c>
    <VirtualHost 0.0.0.0>
        Port    2222
        SFTPEngine  on
        SFTPLog /var/log/proftpd/sftp.log
        SFTPCompression delayed
        SFTPAuthMethods password
        SFTPHostKey     /etc/proftpd/ssh_host_rsa_key
        SFTPHostKey     /etc/proftpd/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
        SFTPHostKey     /etc/proftpd/ssh_host_ed25519_key
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

And in modules.conf, mod_tls and mod_sftp are activated.

I've done some research but didn't find problem like mine. Before this I tried to use mod_ldap to log my AD users but it didn't work as I remember correctly.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This sounds like it might be a bug; could you create a ticket for this in the ProFTPD GitHub project, at https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug related to group names with spaces. More details can be seen here: https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd/issues/1495
One possibility to temporarily solve the problem, in the case of Active Directory, is to change the primary group of the problematic user, from "Domain Users" to one that does not contain spaces.